# save weights and biases from a NN to load them later

Tags: csv, tensorflow, deep-learning, save

I am trying to save the weights and biases from a NN written in Tensorflow 1.4. The NN inside of the class looks like

```
class Model:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__build_flag = -1
        self.__train_flag = -1

    def __model(self, x):
        # Parameters
        dim = self.__dim
        hdim = self.__hdim
        ddim = self.__ddim
        kmatdim = ddim + 1 + dim
        num_layers = self.__num_layers
        std = 1.0 / np.sqrt(hdim)
        std_proj = 1.0 / np.sqrt(dim)
        with tf.variable_scope("Input_projection", 
                               initializer=tf.orthogonal_initializer()):
            P = tf.get_variable(name='weights',
                                shape=(dim,hdim),
                                dtype=tf.float64)
            res_in = tf.matmul(x, P)
        with tf.variable_scope("Residual"):
            for j in range(self.__num_layers):
                layer_name = "Layer_"+str(j)
                with tf.variable_scope(layer_name):
                    W = tf.get_variable(name="weights", shape=(hdim,hdim),
                                        dtype=tf.float64)
                    b = tf.get_variable(name="biases", shape=(hdim),
                                        dtype=tf.float64)
                    if j==0: # first layer
                        res_out = res_in + self.__tf_nlr(
                            tf.matmul(res_in, W) + b)
                    else: # subsequent layers
                        res_out = res_out + self.__tf_nlr(
                            tf.matmul(res_out, W) + b)
        with tf.variable_scope("Output_projection",
                            initializer=tf.orthogonal_initializer()):                         
            W = tf.get_variable(name="weights", shape=(hdim, ddim),
                            dtype=tf.float64)
            b = tf.get_variable(name="biases", shape=(1,ddim),
                            dtype=tf.float64)
            out = tf.matmul(res_out, W) + b

            self.weights = W
            self.b = b
            self.out=out


        return out

    @property
    def save_weights(self):
        assert self.__build_flag == 0, "Run build() first."
        return self.weights
```

With `self.weights` and `self.b`, I have transformed them in instance attributes as they are accessible across the entire class.

If I print the weights in my Jupiter notebook, they look like this:

```
[[ 0.26774276 -0.2249028   0.37067945]
 [ 0.38260571 -0.3644912   0.00079572]
 [ 0.35924226  0.13907322  0.3965674 ]
 [ 0.07286168 -0.39342116  0.04337081]
 [-0.30477155 -0.33258672  0.43377254]]
```

Now, I am trying to save them. I have thought of saving them in a CSV file and reload them again later on. So, I am writing:

```
np.savetxt("dict_weights.csv", model.save_weights, delimiter=",")
```

But, I get the following error

```
----> 7 np.savetxt("dict_weights.csv", model.save_weights, delimiter=",")
      8 # np.savetxt("dict_b.csv", model.save_b, delimiter=",")
      9 

<__array_function__ internals> in savetxt(*args, **kwargs)

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/edmd_DL_new/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py in savetxt(fname, X, fmt, delimiter, newline, header, footer, comments, encoding)
   1370         if X.ndim == 0 or X.ndim > 2:
   1371             raise ValueError(
-> 1372                 "Expected 1D or 2D array, got %dD array instead" % X.ndim)
   1373         elif X.ndim == 1:
   1374             # Common case -- 1d array of numbers

ValueError: Expected 1D or 2D array, got 0D array instead
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the way to do it,

Instead of saving the weights and biases as a CSV, I used :

`tf.train.Saver`

https://github.com/tensorflow/docs/blob/74f7b69f3e7b659bd82146c3db8c68c69a2705c0/site/en/r1/guide/saved_model.md